# How to create a webpage using ASP.NET and C# without using AJAX Toolkit's Tab Container?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a web tool(a script file generator) developed using AJAX Toolkit's Tab Container and Tab Panel.

Here's what the web tool does :

1. Tab 1 : Gets an ID from user and validates the same by connecting to
   a DB
2. Tab 2 : Prompts the user to upload a file and check the format
3. Tab 3 : Allows the user to select a list of items
4. Tab 4 : Creates a script file based on items selected and allows the user to edit the file
5. Tab 5 : Allows the user to download the script file

Insteading of using AJAX's Tab Container, what are the other options I have?
I am not liking this because :

1. Switching Tab is becoming difficult when I use DefaultButton property (I tied the DefaultButton property to a button and I am able to increment the ActiveTabIndex from the corresponding autogenerated class but not when I use DefaultButton property)
2. The UI is not pleasing and it becomes hard to make changes

Comment: use bootstrap `TabPanels`

Comment: can you please walk me through the steps?

Comment: Check this for creating [Tab Panel](https://codepen.io/wizly/pen/BlKxo/)

Answer (score 1):

At the moment one of the most popular ways of displaying a tab control in a web page is using [Twitter Bootstrap Tabs](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp), below is a complete example to help you get started:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#tabs').tab();

        $("#btnGoToTab2").click(function () {
            $('#tabs a[href="#tabTwo"]').tab('show')
        });

        $("#btnGoToTab1").click(function () {
            $('#tabs a[href="#tabOne"]').tab('show')
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="content">
    <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
        <li><a href="#tabOne" data-toggle="tab">Tab One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabTwo" data-toggle="tab">Tab Two</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tabOne">
            <h1>Tab One</h1>
            <input id="btnGoToTab2" type="button" value="Go To Tab 2" />
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tabTwo">
            <h1>Tab Two</h1>
            <input id="btnGoToTab1" type="button" value="Back To Tab 1" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please explain how I can link my C# class to the tabs? Say, in Tab 1, the user types a number. I have a C# class which should get the number entered by the user and connect to a DB and fetch values based on the input number by the user.

Comment: Just place a textbox and button controls in tab1 -> handle the click event of the button -> write c# code in the code behind to talk to the database